# Inverse Galois Problem and Generic Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

In the Wikipedia, the section of Inverse Galois Theory mentions following:

> There also are groups known not to have generic polynomials, such as the cyclic group of order 8.

If we look $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{41})$, its Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic of order $40$; if $H$ is its subgroup of order $5$, then its fixed-field will be extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $8$, with cyclic Galois group of order $8$. Then, what the above statement is saying? Is it difficult to construct an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $8$ with cyclic Galois group?

Comment: Did you already look for an irreducible polynomial $x^8+a_7x^7+\cdots +a_0$ having Galois group $C_8$?

Comment: The generic polynomial for $G$ is a way to construct all the Galois extensions $F/\Bbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$, not only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it difficult to construct an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $8$ with cyclic Galois group of order $8$?*

Here is a monic irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ of degree $8$ having Galois group $C_8$:
$$
f=x^8-17x^6+68x^4-85x^2+17.
$$
For a reference see for example the article "*Some polynomials over $\Bbb Q(t)$ and their Galois groups*" by G. Smith in Mathematics of Computation Volume 69, Number 230, Pages 775-796 (2000).

The Galois group of $f$, as a transitive subgroup of $S_8$, is generated by $\sigma=(14378562)$.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing ONE polynomial  whose splitting field has a specific group as its Galois group is usual Inverse Galois Problem. That is possible for any cyclic group. And there exist infinitely many extensions with $C_8$ as Galois group: take any prime number $p$ of the form $8n+1$, then the $p$ cyclotomic extension has a degree 8 cyclic Galois extension. Generic Polynomial means ALLL these extension to be described through a ONE polynomial in many variables as the following example suggests:

Now look at the polynomial $x^2-y\in \mathbf{Q}[x,y]$ in two variables over rationals.
Now any extension of Q  with Galois group $C_2$ is obtained by giving special values for the variable y as a square-free integer. This two variable polynomial is called generic for $C_2$.
What is claimed is there is no generic polynomial (multi-variable) where specialising values for the extra variables lead to EVERY possible one variable polynomial with $C_8$ as Galois group.